# Magento Admin Menu doesn't work

Tags: adminhtml, routing, adminmenu

I need to have 2 submenus in one menu in `System` menu.

It shows for me 2 submenus, **but** clicking on it just redirects a browser to the front page.

This is my `config.xml` part:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <sphinxsearch>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>AD_SphinxSearch_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>sphinxsearch</frontName>
            </args>
        </sphinxsearch>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

This is my `adminhtml.xml` part:

```
<menu>
    <system>
        <children>
            <sphinxsearch module="sphinxsearch">
                <title>Sphinx Search</title>
                <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
                <depends>
                    <module>AD_SphinxSearch</module>
                </depends>
                <children>
                    <wordforms module="sphinxsearch">
                        <title>Word Forms</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>sphinxsearch/wordforms</action>
                    </wordforms>
                    <stopwords module="sphinxsearch">
                        <title>Stop Words</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <action>sphinxsearch/stopwords</action>
                    </stopwords>
                </children>
            </sphinxsearch>
        </children>
    </system>
</menu>
```

And this is a structure of controllers:

AD

- SphinxSearch
- - controllers
- - - - Adminhtml
- - - - - StopwordsController.php
- - - - - WordformsController.php

Each class (`AD_SphinxSearch_Adminhtml_StopwordsController`, `AD_SphinxSearch_Adminhtml_WordformsController`) extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` and has `indexAction` methods.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergi,In `config.xml` file module is not right, it should be `AD_SphinxSearch` from `AD_SphinxSearch_Adminhtml`

```
<admin>
     <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <ad_sphinxsearch before="Mage_Adminhtml">AD_SphinxSearch_Adminhtml</ad_sphinxsearch>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

And in `adminhtml.xml` file there are lot of issue. syntax is not proper

```
  <adminhtml>
    <!-- define menu -->
    <menu>
      <sphinxsearch module="sphinxsearch">
        <title>SphinxSearch</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <wordforms module="sphinxsearch">
            <title>wordforms Page Title</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/stopwords</action>
          </wordforms>
          <stopwords module="sphinxsearch">
            <title>stopwords Page Title</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/stopwords</action>
          </stopwords>
        </children>
      </sphinxsearch>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <sphinxsearch translate="title" module="sphinxsearch">
              <title>SphinxSearch</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
                <wordforms translate="title">
                <title>Wordforms Page Title</title>
                </wordforms>
                <stopwords translate="title">
                <title>Stopwords Page Title</title>
                </stopwords>

              </children>
            </sphinxsearch>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
  </adminhtml>
```

Comment: you are welcome...:)